# Finding the basis of all polynomials of the form : $a+bx+cx^{2}$ such that $a+3c=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I replaced $a$ with $-3c$ and now i'm stuck with $-3c+bx+cx^{2}$ and i don't know how to continue.Perhaps someone could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with $p(x) = a+ bx +cx^2 = -3c + bx + cx^2 = bx + c(x^2-3)$. This shows $x, x^2-3$ are the basis polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see it as follows, the space of all polynomials $a+bx+cx^2$ has dimension three, as you have three choices ($a,b,c$). Now you have only two remaining choices, since $a=3c$. You can only "choose" $b$ and $c$.